# AngularJS: Karma + Jasmine to test with _real_ backend

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Going to run Karma+Jasmine to test angularjs client with *real* backend. Since Karma is using its own `express` but I need to access real nodejs backend with DB and other stuff, I'm thinking on adding interceptor into `$httpProvider.interceptors` that will just replace my calls to `/api` and redirec them into *real* backend location. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do that on unit tests (and personally I wouldn't even do that with E2E tests).

When doing unit tests, the `$httpBackend` get swapped with a dummy version that is not capable of doing real requests. That is intentional. You shouldn't do any test with the real backend.

On the other hand, there are E2E tests (where you test all your system together) where you could use the real backend in your tests (there are people who likes that, people who doesn't).

Keep in mind that unit test are all about **units** in isolation, that means that you don't care about dependencies and much much less about a backend.

Comment: good answer. That's all about testing philosophy. Mocking requests with $httpBackend will require lots of changes if backend API changes and vise versa. So, thanks for your answer, I must think on designing test philosopy first.

Comment: Indeed, but still your angular stuff shouldn't be coupled in terms that any change on the backend would change how your angular works. Big changes on the backend would mean changes on the tests (independently of the fake backend) so you would only need to change some REST endpoint routes on your `$httpBackend` time to time.

Comment: That'll be hard to follow in two cases: 1.when you i integrate testing at some point in project not start and you rely heavily on api calls (suppose your app literally consumes in api calls) and each of the api calls provides huge sets of data (say stock market app)..so what do you propose in such cases?